# Memory Leak in php?

Tags: php, curl, pdo, memory-leaks

Please i need some help. My php code crashes after a random time and i don't know why.I would like to know if it could be the memory leak problem.I dont' know if i have some problem of memory in my script.My code is more or less the following :

```
<?php 

$url='******';

$bdd= '' ;
$user = 'root';
$password = '*******';
$server = '127.0.0.1';
$db = 'log_database';
$db2 = 'log_stockage';


try
 {
        $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db",$user,$password,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        $bdd2 = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db2",$user,$password,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
 }
 catch (Exception $e)
 {
        die('Erreur  : ' . $e->getMessage());
 }


while(true)
{

        $options=array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_HEADER => true
                        );

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl,$options);

        try
        {
                $content = curl_exec($curl);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
                die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        curl_close($curl);                               


// i use the variable $content to load some table in my database

$bdd->exec ("INSERT INTO ***** (****) VALUES ('*****')");
$bdd2->exec("INSERT INTO ***** (****) VALUES ('*****')");

        sleep(6);

}

?>
```

Comment: The word "crashes" can be used for number of things. Please, be more specific.

Comment: Maybe you can read your apache logs. It's hard to help you with the current informations.

Comment: please fill in more information on the error and code to help you